# GMail desktop web client does not support 'class' attribute anymore?

Tags: css, gmail

Does anybody noticed GMail client for desktop browsers does not support "class" attribute in html tags of email anymore?
This official example doesn't work anymore, starting from today, at my mail boxes:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .colored {
      color: blue;
    }
    
    #body {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='body'>
    <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
    <p class='colored'>This text is blue.</p>
    <p>Jerry</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

"This text is blue" is not blue anymore:

[image: gmail test]

But replacing class='colored' to style='color: blue' works well:

[image: gmail test]

Emails sent from my app look awful in Gmail now... I checked few accounts, this is very strange.

I cannot find any official note about this change. Does anybody know if it's temporary issue or new rules for html email parser?

I can of course change all classes to inline style definitions, but there is just one problem: media queries. I guess I cannot define media queries inline. Official google page says GMail support media queries and it used to work very well till yesterday.